# Why map $x\to \frac{x}{|x|^2}$ map disc to half space?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, geometry, partial-differential-equations, proof-explanation

I was reading Gilberg And Trudinger. In that one of the proof Author mentioned that

map $x\to \frac{x}{|x|^2}$ map disc to half space.
[image]

[image]

I tried with $(\pm 1/n,0)$ and $(0,\pm 1/n)$ It gives points form whole $Z\times Z$ which contradicts with Auther claim. Where I am missing? Please Help me

Any Help will be appreciated

Comment: Observe that $B$ is a ball with $0$ on the boundary. Hence it lies in a half-space and so does the image of $B$ under this map.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir.

Comment: This map is called the **inversion** with center (or pole) the origin and power 1.